# Why do i get this error in the following code? IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

```
from tkinter import *
alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def callback(x):
    label.configure(text='Button {} clicked'.format(alphabet[x]))

root= Tk()

label = Label()
label.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=26)

buttons= []*26  #create a list to hold 26 buttons
for i in range(26):
buttons[i] = Button(text=alphabet[i], command = lambda x=i: callback(x))

buttons[i].grid(row=0,column=i)

mainloop()
```

When this code is run it yields the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./alphabet_click.py", line 16, in 
buttons[i] = Button(text=alphabet[i], command = lambda x=i: callback(x))
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

What do I need to do to resolve this error?

Comment: `[]*26` is still an empty list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jonsharpe said, `buttons` equals to `[]` after
`buttons= []*26`. So just remove `*26` and replace `buttons[i] = Button(...)` by `buttons.append(Button(...))` or using a map :

```py
buttons = list(map(lambda letter: Button(text=letter,
                                         command=callback), alphabet))
```

Comment: This works just perfectly. Thank you so much @qouify.

Answer (score 0):

create a list of alphabets and remove button list will do

```
from tkinter import *
alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
alphabetlist = list(alphabet)
print(alphabetlist)

def callback(x):
    label.configure(text='Button {} clicked'.format(alphabet[x]))

root= Tk()

label = Label()
label.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=26)

for i in range(len(alphabetlist)):
    buttons = Button(text=alphabetlist[i], command = lambda x=i: callback(x))
    buttons.grid(row=0,column=i)

mainloop()
```